# Reading multiple *txt files into multiple arrays in the subdirectory

Tags: perl

I have multiple `subdirectories` and within each of them I have different number of `txt` files. I am trying to read each of the `txt` files into an `array` from each `subdirectory`. Note that each `subdirectory` has different number of `txt` files.  I struggled to find that somebody did something similar. Does anybody has some suggestion where to look, how to do it or something like this?

I have found some example how it can be done by using `server command`, but I it fails to do what I want. I am also a bit confused how to name each `array` although within different `subdirectory` arrays can have same names like `array1, array2, array3..`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Glob;


my $txt;
my @fh;
my @table;
my $table;

for my $txt(glob'*.txt')
{
open my $fh,'<',$txt;
print "$txt\n";
for (my $txt =1 ;$txt <=8; $txt++)  
{ 
    open ($fh,"server$txt"); 
    while (<$fh>) 
    { 
        chomp; 
        my @values = split " ",$_; 
        push @{ "table$txt"},\@values;
        print "$table$txt\n";
    }
}
}
```

I can use this `bash script` to run `perl script` on all `subdirectories`:

```
for i in `ls -d */`;do cd $i; pwd; for j in *txt; do perl ../foo.pl $j; done; cd ../ ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, I only typed the code into the window.  I am also rusty on my perl and do things in a blunt manner.

Assuming all the text dirs are under one main directory. You open the main directory using opendir.  You then read all the entries in the main directory and test to see if the entry is a subdirectory(where the .txt files will be).

Accessing the sub directory, you then you test for the .txt extension using glob and regex which will return an array, pushing the array into the main array, creating an array of arrays.  You can look up how to iterate over this structure to get your information.

```
@all_subdirs;

$main_dir = "C:\main_dir";

my @files;
opendir (DIR,$main_dir) || die $!;
@files = readdir (DIR);
closedir (DIR) || die $!;

$i = 0;

foreach $subdir(@files){
  if(-d $sub_dir){    #-d tests for directory
    @tmp = glob "$main_dir\$subdir\*.txt";
    $all_dirs[$i] = [ @tmp ];
     $i++;
  }
}
```

This stores the subdir array as an array reference.  To get an array back, you need to dereference it as follows:

```
$arrayref = $all_subdirs[0];
@an_array = @$array_ref;
```

Comment: after declaring each variable it gives me an error of `syntax error at try.pl line 21, near "$all_dirs["`. I actuallydon't have to enter each subdirectory, but lets say that the script and txt files are in the same directory, I just need to read each txt file into seperate array and to asses it as lets say `@array, @array1..` and so one depending how much txt files are inside..

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear whether you wish to read the *names* of the files into an array, or the *contents* of the files.

In the former case, you may benefit from the `File::Find` module to collect all filenames in a specific directory and its subdirectories; in the latter case you should use both `File::Find` and `File::Slurp` to read the contents.

Comment: I want to read content of each txt file into an array and if there are five txt file to asses and name them as `@array1, @array2...5`. Hm I have never used this modules.. I actually dont even have to asses each subdirectory. Lets say that the script and files are in the same directory, just need to read each of them into seperate array..

Comment: To read the contents of a file into an array, line by line, Perl has a very easy syntax:
`sub read_file {
my $file = shift;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
my @array = <$fh>;
close $fh;
return \@array;
}`